# If the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent, is the sequence $(a_n - a_{n-1})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ convergent too?

Tags: calculus, limits

If the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent, is the sequence $(a_n - a_{n-1})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ convergent too and if yes what's the limit?

Comment: Note that if $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is convergent, it is Cauchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is convergent. We have that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n-a_{n-1})=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n-\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n-1}=0
$$
using the [properties of the limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Properties).

Comment: Oh, I thought too complicated that I forgot that.. Thank you!

Comment: @fragant You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

If $(a_n)$ is convergent , then it is a [Cauchy sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence) as well.

By the definition of Cauchy sequence, we have that 
$$|a_m-a_n|<\epsilon$$

For $m=n-1$, we have that $$|a_{n-1}-a_n|<\epsilon$$ or $$|a_{n}-a_{n-1}|<\epsilon$$ or $$|(a_n-a_{n-1})-0|<\epsilon$$

Hence by the Epsilon-Delta Definition of limit, we have that the sequence $(a_n-a_{n-1})$ is convergent with limit $0$.

Comment: Sorry can't mark two questions as 'most helpful' but your answer is also correct. Thank you too

Comment: @fragant Its okay . You're welcome.